# how to control the buttons or tabs in the launch application using python

Tags: python

i launched the application using the following code i.e.

import os

cmd = r'start C:\WindowsMediaPlayer\wmplayer.exe'

os.system(cmd)

say i launched win media player.. now i want to control the buttons/the menus to open a file . or do some audio settings.. any thing that is related to media player using the python script.. please any on can help me with this....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a framework such as [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/)
Using this, you can launch windows applications and control them.

Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366293/application-automation-software-tool)

Comment: is there any other way without pywinauto..i.e. only using python/ active python

Comment: without using frameworks, you will have to put in lot of effort. Is there any specific reason for not using pywinauto?

Comment: noting that sort off.. i want to know python a little more in detail.. n i work in a secure environment...

Comment: how can i proceed now...as recently started working on python..only a week...can u help me with this...

Comment: using pywinauto, you again work with python except that you might not be working closely with the OS.

Comment: http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html this url has all details.  This video can also help http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=UsingpyWinAutoToControlAWindowsApplication&fromSeriesID=7#

Comment: There's nothing to download at the pywinauto project web site.

Comment: The link to download was provided in the docs. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/files/

Comment: hey can you tell me which is the alternate way to control the application... i need to present both the options..

Comment: I have posted one more link in the answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366293/application-automation-software-tool

Comment: hey what are the supporting packages needed for pywinnauto...                                                       # Ctypes http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/ (download from http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=71702)
# Sendkeys http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/index.html.... Are these compulsory for python 2.7.1... if yes then i have to send it for approval....there are some optional do i need those......

Comment: These are not compulsory for 2.7

Comment: hey i have to use only python to control windows application.. can you just tell me where to start ..i have tried diff methods..to invoke.. n for controlling i was unable to do so....please help

Comment: This is an alternate way  http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/   It is mentioned in the python docs http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#pywin32